# Date drop down calendar not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a field called date of type date (TextMode =date) in my form. It works on chrome and Firefox giving me a drop down calendar as expected. However it does not work with Internet explorer all versions.What can i do to get it to work in IE. I am aware of using j query etc but is there any way to make this inbuilt date function in asp.net tow work.

here is the HTML

```
 <td class="style12" valign="top">
                    <strong>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_date" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" 
                        Height="25px" style="margin-left: 0px" TextMode="Date" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </strong>
                </td>
```

Comment: that is not an asp.net inbuilt function, but a browser native html5 function - and only IE versions 10 or newer support it... for older versions you will have to use a third party solution (AJAX Control Toolkit, jQuery UI, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>


<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks I am just learning so please bare with me. Where do I put this code. Do I have to import anything for ajax??

Comment: You Need to download  "Ajax Control Toolkit .NET 3.5" http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091.. Then add the dll file in your AJAX Extension in ToolBox in Designer page. Finally add the above code in your Design page

Comment: Or add .dll file in your Bin folder.. easy way